# constant kernel crash in Delaunay triangulation code (Cython)

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, cython, delaunay

EDIT:

After much testing the problem has been found to be in the following loop. I put the loop in its own function. The use of it is to accept a pointer to an array of Vertex structs and remove all repeated Vertices. This is done by checking their id and not comparing their coordinates. Because each Vertex is given a unique id at the very start, it makes it more straightforward like this.

The code to fix would then simplify to this

The basic structures:

```
ctypedef struct Vertex:
    double x
    double y
    int vid_nr

    


cdef Vertex create_vertex(double x_coord, double y_coord, int vid_number):
    cdef Vertex v
    v.x = x_coord
    v.y = y_coord
    v.vid_nr = vid_number
    return v


cdef Vertex* alloc_varr(int size, double var):
    cdef Vertex* varray = <Vertex*>malloc(size * sizeof(Vertex))
    cdef size_t i
    for i in range(size):
        varray[i] = create_vertex(var, var, i)
    return varray
```

The basic deallocation method. Tested and functions as expected

```
cdef Vertex* dealloc_from_varray(Vertex* original_array, int current_size, int remove_index):
    #careful remove_index is actual position - 1

    cdef Vertex* new_array = <Vertex*>malloc((current_size-1) * sizeof(Vertex))
    cdef size_t i
    cdef size_t j
    cdef int upper_limit = remove_index
    for i in range(upper_limit):
        new_array[i] = original_array[i]
    for j in range(upper_limit+1, current_size):
        new_array[j-1] = original_array[j]
        
    free(original_array)
    return new_array
```

And now the method that deallocates repeated Vertices by vid_nr

```
cdef void dealloc_non_uniques(Vertex* free_varray, int size):
    cdef int k = 0 # Initialize k
    cdef int l = 1 #initialized at first iteration but to be safe
    cdef int vsize = size
    #dealloc all non-unique verrtices from the free arr
    while k < vsize - 1:
        l = k + 1
        while l < vsize:
            if free_varray[l].vid_nr == free_varray[k].vid_nr:
                free_varray = dealloc_from_varray(free_varray, vsize, l)
                vsize = vsize - 1
            else:
                l = l + 1
        k = k + 1
    size = vsize
```

Below a simple test

```
cdef int varr_size = 7
cdef Vertex* og_array = alloc_varr(varr_size, 0)

og_array[0].x = 0.2
og_array[0].y = 2
og_array[1].x = -1.8
og_array[1].y = 0.15
og_array[2].x = -0.1
og_array[2].y = -2.3
og_array[3].x = 2
og_array[3].y = -0.3
og_array[4].x = -1.8
og_array[4].y = 6
og_array[5].x = -3.9
og_array[5].y = -2
og_array[6].x = 1.7
og_array[6].y = -3.4
og_array[6].vid_nr = og_array[5].vid_nr
og_array[2].vid_nr = og_array[4].vid_nr
og_array[3].vid_nr = og_array[4].vid_nr




print(varr_size)
for i in range(varr_size):
    print(og_array[i])


#print("\ntest dealloc_non_uniques:\nwe expect varr_size to be 4")

#dealloc_non_uniques(og_array, varr_size)
```

will crash the Kernel once i remove the comment # and run the `dealloc_non_uniques` method. Why ?

Comment: I think you're going to have a hard time convincing many viewers to even read this wall of text and code, much less downloading your code and debugging it. I strongly suggest you break the problem down to produce a minimum reproducible example. Either start with what you have and strip away unnecessary things until the crash disappears, or start from scratch and build an example until the crash manifests.

Comment: Also post debugging details including information on the OS, Python distribution, stack traces, kernel panic output, etc.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart i managed to isolate the problem in using the range() in the for loop on a dynamic index. The range() creates a constant range so a while loop has to be used.
If i manage to have it fixed i will post here

Comment: When using large points-cloud set, eventually calculating with "double"'s is not enough. Likely the app crashes. See this good work by [Shewchuk](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html) which includes C code for "robust calculations"

Comment: @Ripi2 i actually was reading that article of Shewchuk before i began writing my triangulator but the specific set i am working with has coordinates very far from being incomparable as doubles. With that being said i managed to isolate the problem in a certain part only and edited my question if anyone would like to re-give it a look as i am still confused as to HOW that code snippet is wrong

Comment: What is the *kernel* this crashes? My guess as to the cause: with more than one vertex with same vid_id in successive indices in `free_varry`, you pass already freed chunks to `dealloc_from_varray()`. (Do not set `k = k + 1`, but `k = l`. Better yet, get rid of the nested loop.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time i finally found what the problems were.
First of all, declared variables are immutable. So when i declare the size of the whole mesh as a global, to call it later for plotting reasons, i cannot update it on the fly with the `triangulate` function. This was fairly easy to get around. I can just allocate the appropriate size in memory like `<int*>global_mesh_size = ....` and then modify it inside the triangulate function by equating `global_mesh_size[0]` to the temporary mesh_size `int` i create inside the function itself.

The second error in the first version i posted here was in how the loops were written. Because the final mesh size is unknown, when i iterate through its elements with the intention to remove i have to make sure the loop limits are adjusted dynamically.
This could not be done in a `for range()` loop because `range()` takes the initial input and creates the literal range that will remain static until the loop ends.
Therefore it was necessary to update the range manually in the function and use a `while` loop with a simple break condition. This allowed me to deallocate bad Triangles from the final_mesh without reaching out of bounds elements.

The third error was a very simple syntax mistake in the `sort_by_angle()` function where i was accidentally using the .x instead of the .y coordinate to calculate the temporary vector magnitude before doing the norm and the projection on the x-axis.
This lead to the Vertexes not being correctly sorted most of the time. This was the most time-consuming error to spot because there were many lines of code and i just ended up adding a lot of `print()` statements to see if the algebra was being done correctly.

Overall for the following test unit

```
cdef int varr_ssize = 4
cdef Vertex* og_array = alloc_varr(varr_ssize, 0)
cdef int* global_mesh_size = <int*>malloc(sizeof(int))
global_mesh_size[0] = 0 #dynamically changed through triangulate fx

og_array[0].x = 0.2
og_array[0].y = 2
og_array[1].x = -1.8
og_array[1].y = 0.15
og_array[2].x = -0.1
og_array[2].y = -2.3
og_array[3].x = 2
og_array[3].y = -0.3


cdef Face* testmesh = triangulate(og_array, varr_ssize, global_mesh_size)

print("\nglobal mesh size is:", global_mesh_size[0])
for f in range(global_mesh_size[0]):
    print(testmesh[f])

free(testmesh)
free(og_array)
free(global_mesh_size)
```

gives the correct triangulation of

```
global mesh size is: 2

{'ver1': {'x': 2.0, 'y': -0.3, 'vid_nr': 3}, 'ver2': {'x': 0.2, 'y': 2.0, 'vid_nr': 0}, 'ver3': {'x': -1.8, 'y': 0.15, 'vid_nr': 1}, 'fid_nr': 0}
{'ver1': {'x': 2.0, 'y': -0.3, 'vid_nr': 3}, 'ver2': {'x': -1.8, 'y': 0.15, 'vid_nr': 1}, 'ver3': {'x': -0.1, 'y': -2.3, 'vid_nr': 2}, 'fid_nr': 1}
```

To avoid clutter in this thread i will only link the Github page to the code because it is too long to read comfortably in the forum layout.
As usual only the first few Cells in the notebook are relevant. Anything below the first output is just for testing purposes

[Delaunay triangulation through Bowyer-Watson algorithm](https://github.com/dcthecook/Finite_element_method/blob/main/Triangulation.ipynb)

Thanks to everyone who helped <3

EDIT: For a more complex example
[image: Triangulation]
[image: colors]

Comment: `This was the most time-consuming error to spot because there were many lines of code and I…` didn't present it when seeking help. Take a mental note.

Comment: it was in the first version of the post before i did a full edit. I did not present it because i did not know it was there :(